# Can't get this eloquent query to work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm trying get values from both the UserGroup model and from the group model with (belongsTo method in UserGroup)

In UserGroup model:

```
public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group', 'group_id', 'group_id');
    }
```

My query:

```
$arrayGroupes = UserGroup::from("user_group as ug")
->with( ['group' => function($query){
    $query->select('group_id','name as name_group', DB::raw("IF(restricted=1,1,0) as restricted"), "transfer_only");
}])->select("ug.user_id", "u.first_name", "u.surname")
   ->join("users as u", "u.user_id", "=", "ug.user_id")
   ->whereIn("ug.group_id", [1,2,3,4,5])
   ->where("ug.active", "=", 1)->get();
```

Return `null`
But if only do

```
$arrayGroupes = UserGroup::with( ['group' => function($query){
        $query->select('group_id','name as name_group', DB::raw("IF(restricted=1,1,0) as restricted"), "transfer_only");
    }])->whereIn("group_id", [1,2,3,4,5])
       ->where("active", "=", 1)->get();
```

It works but can't select only some values from UserGroup...
Somebody as an answer to me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$userGroups = UserGroup::from("user_group as ug")
    ->join("users as u", "u.user_id", "=", "ug.user_id")
    ->select("ug.user_id", "ug.group_id", "ug.active", "u.first_name", "u.surname")
    ->with( ['group' => function($query){
        $query->select('group_id','name as name_group', DB::raw("IF(restricted=1,1,0) as restricted"), "transfer_only");
    }])
    ->whereIn("ug.group_id", [1,2,3,4,5])
    ->where("ug.active", "=", 1)
    ->get();
```

Try this out. Not tested.

Comment: I tried and it works but it doesn't seems to use correctly the model. For exemple, I'm using a Trait for encryption in my model (http://www.newbox.ca/ecrypting-stored-data-with-laravel/) but the name of my group is getting back encrypted if I get it with the group function of the UserGroup model but if I'm only getting it with the Group model (without UserGroup) I get the name_group decrypted... But thanks for your help !

Comment: @devvmiller I don't get it. In the query, you can retrieve group name from UserGroup. `$userGroup->group->name` because in query with method returns relation.